# Disable JPanel with visual effect

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I'm looking for a good way to disable a **JPanel**.  I'm using a MVC design for a Java Swing GUI.  I want the **JPanel** to be disabled while the model is processing stuff.  I've tried **setEnabled(false)**.  That disables user input on the **JPanel**, but I'd like it to be grayed out to add a more visual effect.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked into Glass Panes? They are useful for painting over areas which already contain components.
[Take a look](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html)

Answer (score 2):

Disabling JPanel does not disable its children components by default, just blocks the panel. Solution I recommend is to create a JPanel subclass and override the `setEnabled` method like this:

```java
class JDisablingPanel extends JPanel {
    @Override
    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        super.setEnabled(enabled);
        this.setEnabledRecursive(this, enabled);
    }

    protected void setEnabledRecursive(Component component, boolean enabled) {
        if (component instanceof Container) {
            for (Component child : ((Container) component).getComponents()) {
                child.setEnabled(enabled);

                if (!(child instanceof JDisablingPanel)) {
                    setEnabledRecursive(child, enabled);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

JPanel doesn't appear any different when disabled, you'll have to override the paintComponent() method to draw it differently (or with a different color) when it is disabled.
Something like this might work:

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    if (this.isOpaque()) {
        Color color = (this.isEnabled()) ? this.getBackground() : this.getBackground().brighter();
        g.setColor(color);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to apply a visual effect its better to use Glasspane. Check [this article](http://www.jroller.com/gfx/entry/wait_with_style_in_swing).
[SwingX](http://wiki.java.net/bin/view/Javadesktop/SwingLabsSwingX) already provides the components you need and much more. Check out the demo on the site for various components available.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use JXLayer framework. It is much more flexible then glass pane. Take a look at the project and [this](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/2008/07/13/jxlayer-30-lockableui) article